# Physics engine for Billiard game

Tags: c++, opengl, physics

I need to write a simple 3D billiard game using OpenGL. Which physics engine is simple and best to use in this case? Or it's better to write physics by myself?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a 2d physics simulation? After all, the action of the game all takes place within 2 dimensions, unless you're hitting the ball too hard or too low. But other than that the balls generally collide at their middle with all other objects in the game. I don't see why you couldn't just use a 2d simulation. Going full 3d physics just to allow players to knock the ball off the table seems overkill.

Comment: Applying spins is a core mechanic of a billiard game. I don’t see how that would work with a 2d engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a simple *2D* billiard-like game using Box2D before.

As Digital Architect pointed out, unless the ball jumps from the table, 3D physics is overkill. And you *can* use 2D physics with 3D graphics.

If you decided to implement physics by yourself, this is what you'd have to do (which are already implemented in Box2D):

1. Circle-Circle collision detection (when balls collide)
2. Circle-Polygon collision detection (when balls collide with the edges, which are **not** rectangles)
3. Handling collision (so that balls that collide move accordingly, depending on the coefficient of restitution)
4. Damping
5. Applying forces (or at least set the velocity of a ball)
6. Sensors (for the holes)

Also, you'd have to make sure everything works properly (no obvious bugs, which can be a pretty hard problem unless you really know what you are doing) and efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, using 2D engine was obvious solution. Hope this will work for me.